# When "SecurityException: Incorrect signature" can happen?

Tags: java, android, securityexception

I have an app that uses PhoneNumberUtil from libphonenumber.jar of google.
All works fine except that I got this stack from a remote crash log.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Incorrect signature
   at org.apache.harmony.security.utils.JarUtils.verifySignature(JarUtils.java:171)
   at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.verifyCertificate(JarVerifier.java:289)
   at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.readCertificates(JarVerifier.java:258)
   at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:378)
   at libcore.net.url.JarURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(JarURLConnectionImpl.java:226)
   at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:436)
   at java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(Class.java:1114)
   at com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.loadMetadataFromFile(SourceFile:603)
   at com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.getMetadataForRegion(SourceFile:2014)
   at com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.parseHelper(SourceFile:2893)
   at com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.parse(SourceFile:2755)
   at com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.parse(SourceFile:2745)
```

I can't reproduce the problem (and its works fine for the most of the users).
Do someone has any suggestion how it can happen? and any way to fix it? (I didn't know how to reproduce the problem on my environment)

Any help would appreciate.

Comment: could be a missing or corrupt certificate on the device.

Comment: There is something that I can do as a developer?

Comment: If this is really the cause - no.

Comment: are you using https services?

Comment: Happens to our app too in API 21